# Laravel whereJsonContains() no retorna nada

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Tengo un modelo que tiene una columna `JSON` llamada `extras` con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "class_dates": [
        {
            "people": "0",
            "datetime": "2023-09-04T12:00"
        },
        {
            "people": "666",
            "datetime": "2024-05-27T12:00"
        },
        {
            "people": "555",
            "datetime": "2025-01-13T12:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Y quiero filtrar el modelo por un extracto de un `string`, por unos filtros, solo soy capaz de obtener mes y año como "2023-09" o "2025-01".

Terminé con la siguiente consulta:

```
    $products = Product::whereJsonContains('extras->class_dates', [
        ['datetime' => '2025-01-13T12:00'],
    ])->get();
```

Que funciona perfectamente y me muestra el resultado que debería.

Pero el tema es que no tengo el `string` completo de la fecha, solo un fragmento como "2023-09" o "2025-01" y no he encontrado la forma de cambiar el operador del arreglo del `whereJsonContains()`.

He intentado:

```
    $products = Product::whereJsonContains('extras->class_dates', [
        ['datetime' => ['LIKE', '2025-01%']],
    ])->get();
```

Pero no me retorna ningún resultado.

También he intentado filtrar por `people`:

```
    $products = Product::whereJsonContains('extras->class_dates', [
        ['people' => '666'],
    ])->get();
```

Que también funciona perfectamente, pero cuando uso el operador `>=` que, en teoría, debería de retorna el mismo resultado, no retorna nada.

```
    $products = Product::whereJsonContains('extras->class_dates', [
        ['people' => ['>=', (int) '666']],
    ])->get();
```

En resumen, me gustaría poder cambiar el operador de la condición interna de `whereJsonContains`.

Actualmente estoy filtrando los resultados usando el operador `REGEXP`, de esta manera:

```
Product::where('extras->class_dates', 'REGEXP', '2025-01')->get();
```

Y sí me filtra como debería, pero usar ese operador me parece muy costoso y me gustaría una solución con `whereJsonContains()` y el uso de otros operadores dentro de esa función